# Replace OAuth2RestTemplate with WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Now I have simple `OAuth2RestTemplate` to talk to another microservice configured like this with custom interceptor

```
    private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Bean("oauthRestTemplate")
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(
            OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
        this.restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, oauth2ClientContext);
        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("oauthRestTemplate")
    public CatalogClientRequestInterceptor interceptor() {
        return new CustomClientRequestInterceptor(restTemplate);
    }
```

How can I migrate to new `WebClient`?

More detailed:

1. where to pass `accessTokenUri`, `clientId`, `clientSecret`, `grandType`?
2. How to add my custom interceptor?

Comment: Does the WebClient portion of the reference help https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-webclient-servlet Did you see the WebClient sample application at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/webclient ?

Comment: @RobWinch As I understand Spring will automatically read my properties and  add Bearer token to header, am I right?

Comment: Yes. Spring Boot reads the client configuration and Spring Security will use the client registration repository created from that to automatically obtain an access token to include as a header.